# Rails - inserting a db row via console doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to insert a new record into a SQLiteDB through my Rails console. Simply using `User.create()`.

The row does not appear in my database.The message implies that a user exists, but calling `User.first` returns `null` and checking the database shows an empty table. What am I missing?

Input:

```
console > User.create(name: 'don', email: 'don@gmaill.com', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test')
```

Output:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'don@gmaill.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, name: "don", email: "don@gmaill.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$3EK3L932ryjrJPFIc4E0/uzavrpkWylDRzx4Wkdwzx8d...">
```

User Class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                                        uniqueness: { case_sen,sitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: Can you add the source of the User class?  The 'User Exists' message doesn't mean that a user exists - it just means that the existence query is being run as part of the create process.  Presumably in a validation step.  There may be another validation that is failing.  Source code would help.

Comment: @PeterGoldstein posted user class :)

Comment: ahhh the "test" password was too short my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely validating uniqueness of `email` field. Hence ActiveRecord is issuing a `select` first to check if a record exist with the same email address, and finding one. Hence `Create` is not saving the new record to database.

But `create` returns the object anyway.

You can try this to verify this. Instead of `create`, try `new` followed by `save!`

```
console > u = User.new(name: 'don', email: 'don@gmaill.com', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test')
console > u.save!
```

To get rid of this error, first delete the record that exists in the DB

Answer (score 2):

It's not persisting the User (you can tell by the `rollback` statement). Looks like it's failing a uniqueness validation on the email. You can look at the errors by calling `errors.full_messages` on the `User` you tried to create, or by using `create!` instead of `create`